# Is it possible to convert a generalized type into a union

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Please tell me whether it is possible to deduce the last type (Tasks) without specifying specific values manually?

```js
interface Action {
  move: number,
  eat: string
}

interface Task<A extends keyof Action> {
  action: A,
  value: Action[A],
}

type Tasks = Task<'move'> | Task<'eat'>;
```

Comment: Real example
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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

Answer (score 1):

You can create a "contrived" [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#distributive-conditional-types) to have a union type with `Task` for each key in `Action`. So you don't need to set `Task<"move"> | ... | Task<"other Action keys">` manually:

```
type DesiredTasks = keyof Action extends infer I ? I extends keyof Action ? Task<I> : never : never
// type DesiredTasks = Task<"move"> | Task<"eat"> 
// same as { action: "move"; value: number; } | { action: "eat"; value: string; }
```

#### Why not `Task<keyof Action>`?

All property value types are merged together, e.g. [discriminated union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions) wouldn' work anymore:

```
type Tasks = Task<keyof Action> // {action: "move" | "eat"; value: string | number; }

declare const t1: Tasks
if (t1.action === "eat") t1.value // value: string | number, no good...

declare const t2: DesiredTasks
if (t2.action === "eat") t2.value // value: string ✔
```

[Sample TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=24&ssc=51&pln=20&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIILMA9iZBvAKGWQFssA3CALmRAFcSAjaAGiOQjjBoGcwpQAcwIBfAgVCRYiFABU4PANYAeVBwAekEABMeyRRACeWGGgzYQAPnztEmHDVRti5OABs61M-ZABtVAC6bGIEYIYADnIKinoAvMjySsoGxqboPpYA3AQA9DnIYAAWwHoA7sBubqTQgijuVeFQEOTYdDxuhsjaJQgCJKBcENrIjViRUGHIrh4oYZF6YFi1RdDicygAIhA8wE3aiYoAsnD07sjxB8oA5GSUV9YAPgnR15xg97n5RSXI5ZUjTR40EoXR6fQGkGGo3Gk2mngKEW2LGQjDoYGQ9X0Rj0hTgIMWKJQQPRJBOdHqhjWiOQWx2ewOcSxqW8Fg0Wl0yFAMGgyAAksgAPx8tkQHR6FImFk4QXPJK86w0EDNHmK5VQT4IyI07a7IYM86ylQAIluECNj0NyiNb3NyHE2ggCDccCayAQOD4BQAjDQGRJTAAKMBegB0dlZsUjyGtXCNAEpvSG4Sg8lN3J5ePwhMgnvQmKsCA6nS6UO6QJ6wAAmGi03X7aI8f3IIOVsPmaWR%20IxsDxgqt5PIVPJzMCEDCIA)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `keyof` operator as the generic of Task to create a union type

```
type Tasks = Task<keyof Action>
```

Comment: Sorry, I simplified the example

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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